Using right conditionals in a sentence
I want to say that I will help someone with packing things if they plan to travel abroad. Is this a good example of expressing  it?

I will help you with packing now provided you traveling to London tomorrow.


Provided [that] you are travelling. But it seems an odd thing to say that you will help them only on condition that they plan to travel. (If they are not travelling, they won't need help with packing!)

@KateBunting still my 1 example makes sense, right? Like this "I will help you with packing now provided you travel to London" would make zero sense, correct?

No, your example is not a good context for using providing. You should use if there, because that's the "neutral" way of referring to something that may or may not be true (now or in the future). Using provided is a bit formal / legal, and normally implies that the addressee is under some obligation to cause the stated condition to be true. Compare We'll go if you like  (natural) and We'll go provided you like (weird).

This question is similar to: "given that", "if", "providing that", or "assuming"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also Are “if”,“provided”, and “supposing” interchangeable in such conditional sentences? and perhaps others.

@FumbleFingers this is just wrong, yes? "I will help you with packing now provided you travel to London"

It's syntactically valid, but it's a ridiculously unlikely thing to say. As @KateBunting points out, provided / providing implies it is a condition of you offering help that the addressee should travel to London, which doesn't really make sense. On the other hand, I will help you with packing provided / providing you pay for a taxi to get me to your house is fine (but a bit formal).

@FumbleFingers my focus in on the word "now". This is rather formal yet correct"I will help you with packing now provided you traveling to London tomorrow." But this "I will help you with packing now provided you travel to London" is rubbish, yes?

To a first approximation, the word now should never appear before providing (or if). I'm not sure exactly what you intend it to mean, though. It could be now = [I make this offer] given the current [changed] circumstances OR [I will help] at this current time. But that's all Off Topic proofreading, and there are other errors in your text anyway. It's not "formal yet correct" - it's just wrong.

I will help you with packing now [that] you have agreed to pay for a taxi to get me to your house is a context where now modifies the text that follows. But in I will help you with packing now, if you like, the word now modifies the preceding verb help. Very different meanings.

This is rather formal yet correct - "I will help you with packing now provided you traveling to London tomorrow" No, it isn't correct.  I indicated in my first comment that it should be 'provided you are travelling' - and several of us have explained that  it isn't appropriate to use providing in this context.

'I will help someone with packing things if they plan to travel abroad…' isn't a bad example. It's by no means great; it's not good, but it's not bad…
'I will help you with packing now provided you traveling to London tomorrow…' is a bad example, for too many reasons.
Can you find any real examples and Post them here, with links to their sources?


I will help you with packing now provided you traveling to London tomorrow.

Try this:
If you are travelling to London tomorrow, I will help you pack.

OP has enquired:

I want to say that I will help someone with packing things if they plan to travel abroad

You can use other words in place of "if" in a conditional sentence. Your sentence can be expressed in a better way if you use should.
Should you wish to travel to London tomorrow, I can help you in packing your luggage.

Reference Cambridge dictionary:
Conditionals: other expressions (unless, should, as long as)
so long as, providing, or, otherwise , supposing etc.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-other-expressions-unless-should-as-long-as

